# How to send input date from the user and send it to GET request?

Tags: jquery, api, filter, get

This is a request method for calling an API which allow to use filtered request in this syntax so i want to filter only records where "startDate eq trainingDate" So when i replace hard coded date in  like this 2020-03-01 that does work fine but when i want to get date from user as input and console log and shows result in expected format but unfortunately request does not  work with user input.

here is api syntax *https://api.wildapricot.org/v2/Accounts/58293/Events?$filter=StartDate eq 2015-01-15*

This is my code

```
$("#listSessionButton").click(function(){
            const trainingDate = $("#trainingDate").val(); 
            console.log(trainingDate); //**it prints date** 
                api.apiRequest({
                apiUrl: api.apiUrls.events({

                    $filter: "StartDate eq trainingDate"//**but not accesible here**
                    }),
                method: "GET",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {


                },
                error: function(data, textStatus, jqXhr){

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldnt you just:

```
apiUrl: api.apiUrls.events({

     $filter: "StartDate eq "+trainingDate

}),
```